# Shadow/brightness around CSS image

Tags: html, css

I have a circle created using CSS, as you can see below:

```
.circle {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    color: #555555;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 4px solid #333;
}
```

How can I create a shadow/brightness around this circle using CSS, as you can see in the sample image below?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Side note: you should set the `border-radius` to `50%` instead of 50px so you can easily scale the circle if you want to change the size later on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) property which respects the border-radius property.

Something like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BaUmL/)

```
box-shadow: 0 0 1em #FFD800;
```

Answer (score 2):

`box-shadow` is what you want. Add this to your .circle class:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 30px #FFE8AE;
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow for more details about the various properties.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) property:

```
box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 10px #faa;
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xx3aL/)**